# Active Directory - Getting "The Server could not be contacted" Error

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, active-directory

I'm trying to create a DLL that gets all the users from a certain OU group in Active Directory, but I'm getting this two errors:
`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: The server could not be contacted.` and
`System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.`

My code is currently this:

```cs
public static void GetAllADUsers(string output, string filter, int mode) {

    List<string> allUsers = new List<string>();

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://mydomain.COM", filter);

    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll()) {
        allUsers.Add(found.DisplayName);

    }

    if(mode == 1)
        File.WriteAllText(output, allUsers.ToString());
    else
        File.AppendAllText(output, allUsers.ToString());

}
```

My input parameters are:

```
PCControl.PCC:GetAllADUsers("C:\temp\users.csv", "OU=Users,OU=...,OU=...,DC=mydomain,DC=com", 1).
```

I don't know if this helps, but I'm able to use this function into my DLL:
*(That's where I got the PrincipalContext)*

```cs
new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mydomain.COM", user, password) {
    AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure,
    Username = user,
    Password = password

})  {
    Filter = "(objectclass=user)"

}.FindOne().Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
```

Any sugestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: This is a network problem. The computer you're running this on cannot open a network connection to the AD server. The default LDAP port is 389. You will have to make sure no firewalls are blocking the connection.